# Can you pip install a package from source, if it's from another Docker image?

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-packaging

Scenario: We have a private "core" package that lives on AWS in a CodeCommit repo. It is built as a Docker image and put into ECR.

When I'm on my local dev, I have the "core" package in the same root directory as a "celery-app" package. The "celery-app" is also in CodeCommit, and the image builds FROM "core".

I want the code from "core" to be accessible in the "celery-app". When I run the Dockerfile for "celery-app" it *appears* to be installing the package, but when I docker exec into the container, and run `python` and try to import it, I can't. (ModuleNotFoundError).

What am I missing here? Is this possible?

```
# core Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.15

RUN (apk update)
RUN apk add python3 py3-setuptools py3-pip python3-dev gcc curl-dev libcurl libc-dev
RUN if [ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]; then ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python; fi

WORKDIR /core
RUN (pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install -U setuptools)
RUN (pip3 install --upgrade setuptools && pip3 install --upgrade wheel)
COPY . . 
RUN (/usr/bin/env python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed)

# Build as a package
RUN (/usr/bin/env python3 -m pip install --upgrade build)
RUN (/usr/bin/env python3 -m build --no-isolation)
```

```
# celery-app Dockerfile
FROM massworker-core:latest

WORKDIR /celery_app
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install ../core/ --ignore-installed

COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I am a little confused by your description. Are you saying that when you build the Docker image on your local dev box that it successfully builds and installs the `core` package, and then only as you `docker exec` this new image that Python can't find it? Can you run a `find / -name ...` command to find one of the files from this Python module?

Comment: This seems like it should work (I might `RUN pip install .` in the base image).  If you put Docker aside for a minute, could you write a sequence of commands that ran against a new virtual environment that would install both packages?  Does, say, `docker run --rm final-image pip3 list` include the base package?

Comment: @penguin359 yes. It builds fine, and pip installs, but somehow isn't in the python namespace for either the app or the python shell.

Comment: OK, can you run the `find` command and see where it was put? That would greatly aid us in helping identify the appropriate fix for you. If it builts and installed, it should be there and either needs to be moved or added to the `$PYTHONPATH` for it to be found.

Comment: @penguin359 so, yes, find works. If you look in the 2 Dockerfile's you'll see that both the "core" and "celery_app" are in the same root directory. 

What's wild, is if I do `python -m site` I see `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages` as a location, and in that location... I see the "core_0.1.0.dist-info"

How can I be more explicit to put it in the python path?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah, `pip3 list` does show the base package with the correct version. What gives?